Why adding functional derivative of entropy doesn't get an uniform distribution?
From https://mbernste.github.io/posts/functionals/, the functional derivative of entropy  is $−1−logP_x(x)$.
From my understanding, adding this derivative to a distribution, it will get an uniform distribution finally.  Because uniform distribution's entropy is the highest one. However, I tried the visualization but got

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mean = 0; std = 1; variance = np.square(std)
x = np.arange(-20,20,.01)
f = np.exp(-np.square(x-mean)/2*variance)/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*variance))

step = 0.1
for i in range(0, 108):
  f = f + (-1 - np.log(f)) * step # functional derivative
plt.plot(x,f)
plt.ylabel('gaussian distribution')
plt.show()

Is it expected in theory?
